# Erro: EntityType<T> has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Ao rodar minha aplicação, o seguinte erro é gerado:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   BolaoSCA.DataAccess.Context.ApostaEstadoMap: : EntityType 'ApostaEstadoMap' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   ApostaEstado1: EntityType: EntitySet 'ApostaEstado1' is based on type 'ApostaEstadoMap' that has no keys defined.

**Classe ApostaEstado**

```
public class ApostaEstado
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe ApostaEstadoMap**

```
public class ApostaEstadoMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<ApostaEstado>
{
    public ApostaEstadoMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("ApostaEstado");
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        //propriedades
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ApostaEstadoId");
        this.Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("ApostaEstadoNome");
    }
}
```

**Script da tabela ApostaEstado**

```
CREATE TABLE ApostaEstado
(
    ApostaEstadoId int not null auto_increment,
    ApostaEstadoNome varchar(30) not null,

    primary key(ApostaEstadoId)
)Engine = InnoDB;
```

**DataContext**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("name=ConnString") { }

    public virtual DbSet<TimeFutebol> TimesFutebol { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Campeonato> Campeonato { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PerfilAcesso> PerfilAcesso { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Bolao> Bolao { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SystemConfig> SystemConfig { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Rodada> Rodada { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Partida> Partida { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RodadaEstado> RodadaEstado { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApostaEstadoMap> ApostaEstado { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsuarioMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TimeFutebolMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CampeonatoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BolaoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PerfilAcessoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SystemConfigMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RodadaMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PartidaMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RodadaEstadoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApostaEstadoMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Para a entidade ApostaEstado, eu fiz EXATAMENTE o mesmo processo das demais entidades. Como por exemplo a entidade RodadaEstado, que não me retorna nenhum erro. Segue estrutura da entidade RodadaEstado:

**Classe RodadaEstado**

```
public class RodadaEstado
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Rodada> Rodadas { get; set; }

    public RodadaEstado()
    {
        Rodadas = new HashSet<Rodada>();
    }
}
```

**Classe RodadaEstadoMap**

```
public class RodadaEstadoMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<RodadaEstado>
{
    public RodadaEstadoMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("RodadaEstado");
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        //propriedades
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("RodadaEstadoId");
        this.Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("RodadaEstadoNome");
    }
}
```

**Script da tabela RodadaEstado**

```
CREATE TABLE RodadaEstado
(
    RodadaEstadoId int not null auto_increment,
    RodadaEstadoNome varchar(30) not null,

    primary key(RodadaEstadoId)
)Engine = InnoDB;
```

Realmente não sei o que fazer. Já revisei inúmeras vezes as classes ApostaEstado, ApostaEstadoMap, o DataContext e o script do banco, para ver se eu estava fazendo/escrevendo algo errado. Entretanto, não encontrei nenhum erro de estrutura ou código.

PS: Tentei a alternativa do Data Annotation ao associar a notação [Key] ao atributo Id. também não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Tem um erro na declaração no DbSet se colocou a class Map AostaEstadoMap. !!!da uma olhada

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Olhei novamente e não identifiquei esse erro de escrita.

Comment: Ultimo DbSet o tipo esta errado public virtual DbSet<ApostaEstadoMap> ....

Comment: Santo Virgilio!!! Funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Poderia comentar como resposta para eu atribuir como válida a sua resposta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você colocou erroneamente a classe que serve de configuração no lugar da classe que é a entidade.

Está assim:

```
public virtual DbSet<ApostaEstadoMap> ApostaEstado { get; set; }
```

Troque para:

```
public virtual DbSet<ApostaEstado> ApostaEstado { get; set; }
```